# Creating a Snap

Tags: python, dependencies, snap

I have a Python package which I would like to create a Snap for. I had a go at this a couple of years ago and gave up after trying 10-20 versions of the yml file over a couple of months effort. I concluded that I didn't know what I was doing and there didn't seem any expertise around to help.

It has several dependencies - Python3, python3-pillow, Gtk3, and align_image_stack (which is in hugin-tools). In my Debian package these dependencies are easy enough to state. Is there an easy way to do this in a Snap?
Otherwise I imagine I would have to include build commands for align_image_stack and all its dependencies. That wouldn’t be possible for me as the package was written in a compiled language I don't know by someone else and requires compiling, I use an interpreted language and am not familiar with compilation.

Here is an example I have found and modified, is this anywhere near on the right lines? There is no reference to meson.build there.

```
name: {myapp}
version: '0.1'
summary: My application
description: |
 My application for python
base: core18
grade: stable
confinement: strict

apps:
  {myapp}:
    command: bin/{myapp}
    plugs: [home]
    extensions: [gnome-3-34]
parts:
  {myapp}:
    plugin: python
    python-version: python3
    source: .
    stage-packages: [hugin-tools, python3-pillow]
```

Alternatively, since I have already created a working Debian package of {myapp}. Could I just include that somehow and the align-image-stack dependency would be included?

```
name: {myapp}
version: '0.1'
summary: My application
description: |
 My application for python
base: core18
grade: stable
confinement: strict
icon: {myapp}_logo.png

apps:
  {myapp}:
    command: bin/{myapp}
    plugs: [home]
    extensions: [gnome-3-34]
    
parts:
  {myapp}:
    plugin: python
    python-version: python3
    source: .
    stage-packages: [hugin-tools, python3-pillow] 

  archives:                  
    plugin: nil
    stage-packages:
      - libc6
      - python3-pil

    deb:
    plugin: dump
    source: {myapp}_0.0.1_all.deb
```

Edits suggested by commenters:

- popey: Gtk3 -> extensions: [gnome-3-34]

Comment: The [stage-packages] section should list actual package names from the Ubuntu archive, not plain text English names for them. If they don't exist in the archive, they may be in pypi in which case you can list them with a `python-packages` section. If it's a desktop GTK app, maybe consider using the GNOME Extension. https://snapcraft.io/blog/gnome-3-34-snapcraft-extension